# Writing JOIN Commands on Teradata

Tags: inner-join, teradata

q) Use COUNT and DISTINCT to determine how many distinct skus there are
in the skuinfo, skstinfo, and trnsact tables. Which skus are common to all tables, or unique to specific tables?

A) I was trying to find the solution to the above q in **TERADATA**. The first part was simple i was able to run three commands and got the distinct skus (stock keeping unit).

Now to find the common sku in all three table i am running the command but having errors :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.sku),COUNT(DISTINCT b.sku),COUNT(DISTINCT c.sku)
FROM skuinfo a INNER JOIN skstinfo b INNER JOIN trnsact c
ON a.sku=b.sku AND b.sku=c.sku;// Why is there error if i use **Where** in Place of ON?
```

```
**Error Occurred . . .**
[com.teradata.commons.datatools.sqlparsers.common.ParseException: Encountered ";" at line 3, column 31. Was expecting one of: "and" ... "at" ... "cross" ... "day" ... "full" ... "hour" ... "inner" ... "join" ... "left" ... "minute" ... "month" ... "on" ... "or" ... "right" ... "second" ... "timezone_hour" ... "timezone_minute" ... "year" ... "||" ... "(" ... "**" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "mod" ... "." ... "[" ... ]
```

Please let me know why is my syntax not working, though most forums say the query is right. Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is is good way to get your desired result, you seem to join non-unique columns, creating in a huge intermediate result set.

Comment: Are you literally trying `skuinfo a inner join skstinfo b inner join trnsact c WHERE a.sku = b.sku...`?  If so, that's not valid SQL.  I'm not convinced what you have in your post is valid, but even if it is, it's poorly written.  Additionally, since you're using inner joins on the sku column, you're going to get the exact same number for each table.